# Schengen Tourist Visa to Spain - Is EAD/AP with approved I-131 a valid Travel Document (to indicate I will come back to US)?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen in living in the U.S. on a H1-B visa. My Green Card is pending under I-485 Adjustment of Status. My last H1-B visa stamp has expired but I have valid I-797A H1-B extensions. Additionally, I also have EAD/AP combo card with approved I-131 travel document.

Couple months ago, I applied for a Mexican tourist visa since my H1-B stamp had expired. At the Consulate, they asked, "how will you get back to the US?" and my response was that I will use the EAD/AP combo card with approved I-131 to return. The Mexican tourist visa was approved - I went to Mexico and I successfully returned back to the United States with my EAD/AP combo card. I had no issues with the immigration at all.

In August, I want to travel to Spain with my girlfriend (she's US Citizen) and I would like to apply for a Schengen Tourist Visa. On Spain's VAC website, the Schengen Tourist Visa Application Checklist mentions the following **items for Valid Residence Proof**:

- Permanent Residence Card / Green Card ***(don't have this yet)***
- Valid Residence Visa Stamp ***(don't have this)***
- Employment Authorization Document with Advance Parole ***(definitely have this)***
- Refugee Travel Document ***(not applicable to me)***
- Visa must be valid for re-entry into the US if returning to the US ***(my H1B stamp on passport has expired but my I-797A is valid for another year, and I have EAD/AP card)***

**My Question:**

What I am not sure is whether the EAD/AP card is considered a valid travel document and a valid residence proof by Schengen countries. I know it is listed on a checklist, but has anyone got a Schengen Tourist visa with this? Will I get rejected because my H1B stamp has expired even though I have valid I-797A, valid Passport, and valid EAD/AP travel documents?

Comment: If you have the correct documents as stated by the VAC, I wouldn't see an issue here

Comment: The list you cite in the question has your answer, and this question acknowledges that explicitly, but still you aren't certain.  Why don't you trust this official information?  If you have a reason not to trust the list, the question should mention the reason, preferably with links
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list explicitly includes your document, so not sure why you're confused.

Your H1B is irrelevant, you're not currently in H1B status (your last entry was on your AP) and you have no H1B visa.

Comment: "you have no H1B visa" - don't think this is accurate. H1B is dual-intent. It doesn't get invalidated with the use of EAD/AP nor EAD/AP or I-485 AOS gets invalidated if I get a new H1B stamp. I have verified this with multiple immigration lawyers.

Comment: The confusion regarding EAD/AP comes from heresay that Spain (and Schengen countries) are not recognizing EAD/AP cards any more and they explicitly want a visa stamp. I am getting conflicting information. Even there's confusion between clerks who work in the VAC - one thought EAD/AP is valid and other one thought EAD/AP is not valid. And the mistaken concept that once EAD/AP is used, H1B is invalid (I have verified this to be untrue).

Comment: @BlueChips23 Your H1b visa is not invalid because of your immigration intent, but because it expired. Your *status*, once you're paroled, is "paroled", not H1b. The H1b *authorization* is still valid, but you're not currently in H1b status and you do not currently have a valid H1b visa. I cannot speak to the clerks' confusion, but from the requirements you quoted you should have no problems.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Spanish consulate does not accept the EAD/AP as a document to apply for a Schengen visa. I was sent back today because my current H1B visa has expired and they don't accept the EAD as a replacement doc.